# Insert variable as parameter

Tags: javascript, css, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have Javascript code :

```
document.getElementById("Grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "repeat(3, 2fr)";
```

How do I insert variable as argument to modify my CSS style, when I try:

```
"repeat(${MyVariable}, 2fr)";
```

it seems doesn't work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${MyVariable}` belongs in backticks ([template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals))

so EITHER

```
document.getElementById("Grid").style.gridTemplateRows = "repeat("+MyVariable+", 2fr)";
```

OR

```
document.getElementById("Grid").style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${MyVariable}, 2fr)`;
```